# javascript block not recognized in user control

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, user-controls

I would like to expose a very interesting situation, I have several user controls in an .aspx Page, in one of them I have a `<script>` block with a function called "unCheckAll()", I am simply calling the function on the Click event of a radio button but the function is not found, when I click the radio button I got on my browser (Firefox 45.0.1) the error "ReferenceError: unCheckAll is not defined" and it points to my aspx Page which makes no sence because my function is in my ascx, here is the code of my user control:
(The radio button that calls the function is at the bottom)

```html
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Frage3.ascx.cs" Inherits="Fragen_Frage3" %>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Fcss/Fonts.css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Fcss/RadioBtn.css" media="screen"/>

<script src="../Fjs/FragenMethoden.js"></script>

<style>
    .conx {
        width: 50%;
        margin: auto;
        position:absolute;
        top:5%;
        left:25%;
        background-color: rgba(148,148,148,0.07);
    }
</style>

<div id="divcont" class="conx">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <asp:Label ID="lblF3" CssClass="FrageText" runat="server" Text="Welche der unten genannten Leistungen nehmen Sie bei der Raiffeisenbank Oberursel eG in Anspruch?"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblF1Neben" CssClass="SubFrageText" runat="server" Text="(Mehrfachnennung möglich)" Font-Italic="true"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th class="text-center">Regelmäßig</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Gelegentlich</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tr>
                    <td><span style="font-weight:bold;">Filiale</span></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Kompetenz</td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp1" id="rBtnKom1" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Selbstbedienungsgeräte', 'regelmäßig')"> <span></span></label></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp1" id="rBtnKom2" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Selbstbedienungsgeräte', 'gelegentlich')"> <span></span></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Telefonischer Kontakt</td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp2" id="Radio1" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Telefonischer Kontakt', 'regelmäßig')"> <span></span></label></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp2" id="Radio2" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Telefonischer Kontakt', 'gelegentlich')"> <span></span></label></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><span style="font-weight:bold;">Beratung</span></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Anlageberatung (z.B. Sparkonto, Wertpapiere)</td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp3" id="Radio3" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Anlageberatung', 'regelmäßig')"> <span></span></label></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp3" id="Radio4" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Anlageberatung', 'gelegentlich')"> <span></span></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Finanzierungsberatung (z.B. Kredite, Immobiliendarlehen)</td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp4" id="Radio5" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Finanzierungsberatung', 'regelmäßig')"> <span></span></label></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp4" id="Radio6" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Finanzierungsberatung', 'gelegentlich')"> <span></span></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Versicherungsberatung (z.B. Versicherungscheck)</td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp5" id="Radio7" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Versicherungsberatung', 'regelmäßig')"> <span></span></label></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp5" id="Radio8" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Versicherungsberatung', 'gelegentlich')"> <span></span></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Immobilienberatung (z.B. IMAXX Oberursel)</td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp6" id="Radio9" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Immobilienberatung', 'regelmäßig')"> <span></span></label></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp6" id="Radio10" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Immobilienberatung', 'gelegentlich')"> <span></span></label></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><span style="font-weight:bold;">Online</span></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zahlungsverkehr (z.B. Online-Banking)</td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp7" id="Radio11" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Zahlungsverkehr', 'regelmäßig')"> <span></span></label></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp7" id="Radio12" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Zahlungsverkehr', 'gelegentlich')"> <span></span></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Online-Produkte (z.B. VR-BonusSparen)</td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp8" id="Radio13" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Online-Produkte', 'regelmäßig')"> <span></span></label></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp8" id="Radio14" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Online-Produkte', 'gelegentlich')"> <span></span></label></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><span style="font-weight:bold;">Telefon</span></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Kontoservice</td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp9" id="Radio15" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Kontoservice', 'regelmäßig')"> <span></span></label></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp9" id="Radio16" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Kontoservice', 'gelegentlich')"> <span></span></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Terminvereinbarung</td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp10" id="Radio17" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Terminvereinbarung', 'regelmäßig')"> <span></span></label></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp10" id="Radio18" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, 'Terminvereinbarung', 'gelegentlich')"> <span></span></label></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><span style="font-weight:bold;">Sonstige Bank und Zwar:</span></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input name="txtSonstBank" type="text" id="txtSonstBank" size="32"/></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp11" id="Radio41" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, getText(), 'regelmäßig')"> <span></span></label></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp11" id="Radio42" onclick="antwortNehmen(3, getText(), 'gelegentlich')"> <span></span></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span style="font-weight:bold;">Keine Leistungen</span></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="gp12" id="RadioKeine" onclick="unCheckAll()"> <span></span></label></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function unCheckAll() {
        alert('haaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
        return "";
    }
</script>
```

I do not set the unCheckAll function in a separate .js file because it will be very specific for this user control alone.

I thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Have you checked the returned page to see if it really contains that script?

Comment: Since the aspx page is executing the ascx, it makes sense. How do you embed the ascx, how is it called and instantiated?

Comment: At client script time, your script is within the markup defined for the ASPX, so the user control just acts as a placeholder to render the script at that location in the page.  Also, FYI, if you have this control defined more than once, this function is also then defined more than once, and that is a problem...

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Alexander: i have all my ascx registered in my aspx page under the same TagPrefix and then they are called in a div within a update panel on the aspx page, they are just initialized once, basically what I do is to shown them or hide them inside the Panel, I notice something, what I am trying to do (calling a function inside a script block of a user control) works only in the first user control that has a script block.

Comment: Brian Mains, I understand what you mean, then, is there a way to make the user control use its own script code? like a code behind function would.

Comment: Thank for your answers I already figured the problem out and actually solved it, my problem was the one Brian Mains mentioned, the user control was acting as a place holder and not running any script, my solution was to use pure asp instead, I replaced my html radio buttons for asp:radio buttons and just added a click event on the code behind to do the task, pretty simple I guess, I hope this helped someone one day, thanks.